# Using Output Parameter in SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am retrieving the scope_identity of a db entry, and I want to use that variable in a different SqlDataSource, primarily as an  but I am unable to access the variable.
I have the variable being displayed in a msgbox, and it is displaying properly, I am just unsure how to access it in the SqlDataSource. Here is my code;

This is the datasource that inserts the first information and received the scope_identity, as well as the _inserted event;
Code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="InsertPatientInfo" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DataConnectionString %>"
providername="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DataConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
    InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    InsertCommand = "InsertPatInfo"
    OnInserted="InsertPatientInfo_Inserted">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID = "PatInfoName" Name="PatName" PropertyName="text"/>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID = "PatInfoAge" Name="PatAge" PropertyName="text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID = "PatInfoState" Name="PatState" PropertyName="selectedvalue" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID = "PatInfoCountry" Name="PatCountry" PropertyName="selectedvalue" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID = "PatInfoPhone" Name="PatPhone" PropertyName = "text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID = "PatInfoCell" Name="PatCell" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:Parameter DbType="Int32" Direction="Output" Name="PatID" />
    </InsertParameters> 
Protected Sub InsertPatientInfo_Inserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles InsertPatientInfo.Inserted
    Dim PatID As String = e.Command.Parameters("@PatID").Value
    MsgBox(PatID, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
End Sub
```

Here is the call to the next SqlDataSource, with the InsertCommand included, I'm planning on switching to a stored procedure once I get it working; I continue to get the error, that the scalar varaible @PatID is not set, am I supposed to declare it as a  and if so, what type?
Code:

```
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="InsInqInfo" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DataConnectionString %>"
        providerName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DataConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
        InsertCommand = "Insert into tblInquirer(InqPatID, InqName, InqState, InqCountry, InqPhone, InqRelation, InqVia, InqCareLevel, InqProgram) VALUES 
        (@PatID, @InqName, @InqState, @InqCountry, @InqPhone, @InqRelation, @InqVia, @InqCareLevel, @InqProgram)"


<InsertParameters>

            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID = "InqName" Name="InqName" PropertyName="text"/>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID = "InqStateList" Name="InqState" PropertyName="selectedvalue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID = "InqCountry" Name="InqCountry" PropertyName="selectedvalue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID = "InqPhone" Name="InqPhone" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID = "radInqRel" Name="InqRelation" PropertyName="selectedvalue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID = "InitInqVia" Name="InqVia" PropertyName = "selectedvalue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID = "CareLevel" Name="InqCareLevel" PropertyName="selectedvalue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID = "ProgSelect" Name="InqProgram" PropertyName="selectedvalue" />     
        </InsertParameters>
```

Thank you in advance,
Nick

Answer (score 1):

In this `InsertPatientInfo_Inserted` handler, you can assign the output parameter's value as the default value for your other `SqlDataSource` named `InsInqInfo`:

```
Protected Sub InsertPatientInfo_Inserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles InsertPatientInfo.Inserted
    Dim PatID As String = e.Command.Parameters("@PatID").Value
    MsgBox(PatID, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    ' Assign the output as the default for 
    InsInqInfo.InsertCommand("@PatID").DefaultValue = PatID
End Sub
```

I personally would move all this code to a the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this pages to see more information about typed data sources and their parameters..
http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=7074

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228051.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad.aspx

```
<asp:Parameter Name="EmpID" Direction="Output" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
```

check insert statement in this code snippet.

```
<asp:sqlDataSource ID="EmployeeDetailsSqlDataSource" 
  SelectCommand="SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @EmpID"

  InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Employees(LastName, FirstName) VALUES (@LastName, @FirstName); 
                 SELECT @EmpID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()"
  UpdateCommand="UPDATE Employees SET LastName=@LastName, FirstName=@FirstName 
                   WHERE EmployeeID=@EmployeeID"
  DeleteCommand="DELETE Employees WHERE EmployeeID=@EmployeeID"

  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnection %>"
  OnInserted="EmployeeDetailsSqlDataSource_OnInserted"
  RunAt="server">

  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="EmpID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
  </SelectParameters>

  <InsertParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="EmpID" Direction="Output" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
  </InsertParameters>

</asp:sqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I've gone through that tutorial and I believe that my code is exactly in resemblance with his. The problem is that I can't access my @PatID outside of the .inserted event. I put it in the msgbox() and it displays the correct ID, but I am unable to use that as a <asp:controlparameter> with a different SqlDataSource so i can use that as a relational key in another database table. Is there anyway to do this?